# ¿como puedo crear multiples usuarios en django?

Tags: login, modelos

Estoy tratando de crear un sistema de dashboard en el cual lo quiero manejar con los siguientes perfiles.

1. Usuario superadministrador = el cual pueda ingresar a la plataforma, visualizar y administrar todos los perfiles.
2. Usuario administrador = esto los crea el superadministrador y solo tiene que tener derecho a ver sus correspondientes vistas asignadas.
3. Usuario estándar = estos usuarios pueden crearlos los usuarios administradores y pueden tener 3 tipos de perfiles, ejemplo, usuario de publicación, usuario docente, usuario de vista.

es claro tener en cuenta que los usuarios administradores solo podrán ver su propio perfil, y el perfil de los usuarios que le pertenezcan a ese mismo usuario administrador y no pueden ingresar al admin.

cree inicialmente un modelo de amín usuario con AbstractBaseUser, y cree otros modelos para el perfil administrador y usuario, pero cuando los registro y los deseo loguear por parte del perfil administrador y usuario no me deja ingresar, solo me permite el inicio de sesión con los usuarios superadministradores.

dejo un diagrama de más o menos lo que quiero hacer por si no fui muy claro

[image: Ejemplo del modelo]

no se si me puedan colaborar, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No queda claro donde tenes el problema...

Comment: Hola @gbianchi inicialmente pues me gustaría saber cómo hago la estructura del modelo en Django 3 para que sea posible tener los 3 perfiles según la estructura que mencione para que todos los usuarios puedan iniciar sesión y que los usuario de nivel 2 puedan ver solo sus propios usuarios.

Muchas gracias por tu apoyo en aclaración de preguntas.